# Waiting for a function to return before moving to the next line

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am attempting to develop a method which has the following functionality:
- call a function which returns an object of a class
- push this object to an array
- print the new array

The function which returns the object of a class use the exec( ) function to use the command line to execute a script. This may take a number of seconds to complete.

```
SampleFunction(data) {

    const xyzObject = xyz.otherfunction(data); 
    //other function takes a number of seconds to finish

    this.array.push(xyzObject); // Push object onto the array
    console.log(array);
    return xyzObject;
}
```

In my code, the array is printed to the console before the object is even returned. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Ideally: Reorganize your code so that it correctly handles the fact that `exec` is an asynchronous operation. For instance, your function could accept a callback or return a promise, rather than directly returning the result.

As a **very** much second-best answer in most cases: You could use [`execSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options).

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend reading [this blogpost](https://zaiste.net/nodejs-child-process-spawn-exec-fork-async-await/) on the subject.

Basically you need to turn your call into a promise, and then use the async/await operators to pause the thread while you wait for the command to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines could do the job:

```js
// const { exec, execFile } = require('child_process');

const xyz = {
  otherfunction: data => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // you do your exec() here with something like that:
      // exec('<command>', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      // execFile('<file>', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      //   if (err) { reject(err) }

      //   resolve(stdout);
      // });
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(data);
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
};

const SampleFunction = async function(data) {
  let array = [];

  const xyzObject = await xyz.otherfunction(data); 
  //other function takes a number of seconds to finish

  array.push(xyzObject); // Push object onto the array
  console.log(array);
  return xyzObject;
}

SampleFunction([
  {city: 'Los Angeles', state: 'CA', population: '4M'},
  {city: 'New York City', state: 'NY', population: '8.4M'},
  {city: 'Atlanta', state: 'GA', population: '0.5M'},
]);
```

If you actually are executing a script file, I'd recommend to go for `execFile`.